# Azure artifact cannot be uploaded because max quantity has been exceeded or the payment instrument is invalid even I have 0 GB

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have error when trying to upload/publish, I got

> Artifact cannot be uploaded because max quantity has been exceeded or
> the payment instrument is invalid

But in Artifacts storage:

[image]

So what can I do ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are trying to upload/publish artifacts to Azure DevOps, please see your storage bill for Azure Artifacts by following the steps below:

1. Sign in to your organization (`https://dev.azure.com/{yourorganization}`).
2. Select **Organization settings**.
3. Select **Billing**.
4. Find **Artifacts** and see your current billed usage from Azure Artifacts.

[image]

> Azure Artifacts includes a free usage tier of 2 GB. Any usage below
> this level isn't billed to your subscription. Above this limit, we
> charge you for your actual usage. The usage limit allows you to
> control the maximum volume of storage that you're billed for. Once the
> maximum usage limit is reached, you can no longer upload artifacts and
> will need to **either reduce your artifact storage, or increase your
> usage limit.**

More details, check the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/start-using-azure-artifacts?view=azure-devops#faqs

Comment: Can I have overview of those artifcts that occupy space ? I made cleanup but seems is not enough

Comment: Deletion of artifacts doesn't register immediately. Storage usage should be updated within 24 hours, but in some cases it may take up to 48 hours maximum. If you're blocked from uploading artifacts, you can temporarily increase your usage level to continue publishing artifacts. Then, reduce the level once the storage metrics are updated. Check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/start-using-azure-artifacts?view=azure-devops#q-how-long-does-it-take-for-deleted-artifacts-to-affect-the-amount-of-billed-storage.